# Why do we have to use another kernel source from the Internet when implementing a new system call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to add a system call to my OS and when I read the online tutorials, it always starts with downloading and extracting a kernel source code from the Internet. For example:

`$ wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.4.56.tar.xz` to download the `.tar.xz` file.

And `$ tar -xvJf linux-4.4.56.tar.xz` to extract the kernel source code.

My question is: why do we have to use another kernel source from the Internet? Can we add the new system call to the running OS and compile it directly?

Comment: *"compile it directly"* - what do you mean?

Comment: There is no possibility of dynamically adding syscalls. It is because **adding** new **syscall** is an **unnatural need**. So you should recompile and install modified kernel. The Linux kernel community does its best to make development easy, but within reason.

Comment: I mean can we add the new system call to the source code of the currently running OS and compile it? Instead of downloading source code of the new one.

Comment: Do you have a very expensive Internet channel? What's the problem with downloading? Usually, the complete kernel source code is not included with Linux distributions. It is also an unnatural need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a system call to my OS and when I read the online tutorials, it always starts with downloading and extracting a kernel source code from the Internet.

Well, that's right. You *need* to modify the kernel source code in order to implement a new syscall.

> why do we have to use another kernel source from the Internet?

It's not "another kernel source", it's just "a kernel source". You don't usually have the source code for your currently installed kernel already at hand.

Normally, most Linux distributions provide a *binary* package for the kernel itself (which is automatically installed), a package for its *headers* only (which can be used to compile new modules), and possibly a *source* package related the binary package.

For example, on Ubuntu or Debian (assuming that you have [enabled source packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121041/how-to-download-debian-packages-source-code)) you should be able to get the current kernel source:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Since the tutorial author cannot possibly know which kernel version or which Linux distribution you are using, or even if your distribution provides a kernel source package at all, they just tell you to download a kernel source package from that Linux kernel website. This also ensures you use the exact same version that is shown in the tutorial, to avoid any compatibility problem with newer/older kernel versions.

Furthermore, you usually *don't want* to play around with the kernel of the machine you are using, since if something bad happens, you can end up damaging your system. You usually want to use a virtual machine for experimenting.

> Can we add the new system call to the running OS and compile it directly?

Not really, it's not possible to hot-patch a new syscall into a running kernel. Since you need to modify the source code, first of all you need to have the source. Secondly, you'll need to do whatever modification you need and then compile the new kernel. Thirdly, you'll need to properly install the new kernel and reboot the machine.